# Bulk changing pictures without any perceptible visual difference

Tags: command-line, image-editing

I need to upload some photos to a website, I already uploaded the same photos to the website in the past, now I removed them from the website and I'm not allowed to upload the same exact pictures again. Every time I find myself in this situation I have to take new photos of the same thing and upload the new ones to the website, I'm allowed to do that. I suspect that the websites has a database with old pictures, so that it can check if a picture was previously uploaded.
In order to not take every time new photos, I would like to edit the previous ones in such a way that they look exactly the same but they don't get detected as previously uploaded photos.

I'm not aware of what kind of algorithm they use, but I want to experiment things like: changing just one pixel, change the hue/saturation/etc of the picture by a very small amount. This way, hopefully, the "new" picture will look the same and I will be still able to upload it.

I would prefer a command line solution for Windows but a Linux one is fine anyway. Something like this:

```
change_picture_but_not_really.exe photo1.png photo2.png photo3.png
```

I think also some graphic editor advanced functionality would be fine. I remember Photoshop is able to automate some tasks (with GUI), currently I'm using GIMP, is it capable of something similar for what I need?

I'm also aware that [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_messages) exists, I don't think it's a perfect solution, but maybe it's fast (if someone can suggest some CLI programs...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example ImageMagick. And for example to change the exposure by +3 (10 is about one stop) you can use command:

```
convert in_file -evaluate add 3% out_file
```

to change saturation by +5% you can use command (mass change):

```
magick mogrify -modulate 100,105,100 *.jpg converted_%03d.jpg
```